# Order the following functions in terms of O notation. Is there a quick way?

Tags: limits, notation, asymptotics

Order the following functions in terms of little oh notation:

[image]

where: 
[image]

Im actually confused on how to do it. I think its the functions that confuse me not the method on how to do it.

I know that: 
[image]

 But either my mathematical skills are failing me or there's a different way to do it, that  I don't know.  
Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: As $n\to+\infty$, $\log n$ grows slower than any $n^\alpha$ ($\alpha > 0$).

Comment: What @Amateur_Algebraist said.  $\log n$ is **far far** smaller than $n$.  So much smaller that any power $(\log n)^a$ is smaller than any power $n^b, b>0$.  If you don't already know this, then the way to do it is to compute $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\sqrt{n}}{n(\log_7 n)^2} .$$